# How to properly set parent of a widget in Pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I have the following code

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from mw import Ui_MainWindow as mwin
from wd import Ui_Form as wdg

class widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
            super(widget,self).__init__(parent)
            self.ui = wdg()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)
            self.show()

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        super(Main,self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = mwin()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()
        w = widget(self)
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        mn = Main()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The Ui is generated by qt designer and is imported from another file.

When I run the code, both the Main window and widget are merged together and a segmentation fault occurs when I close the Main window.

When I set the parent in the widget as None the problem goes but the widget has no parent.

I am unable to understand what is wrong and how to correctly set the Main window as the parent of the widget ?

Comment: You should not use show() in the class constructor. Remove them and call mn.show() before starting your QApplication.

Comment: Can you add mwin and wdg code as well?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the correct way but works.

Workaround:

```
class widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        super(widget,self).__init__()
        self.ui = wdg()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.parent = parent

        self.show()


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
    super(Main,self).__init__(parent)
    self.ui = mwin()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.show()
    w = widget(self)
```

then use self.parent

Comment: the whole idea is running .show() once... and not multiple times.

Comment: @Ujjwal A good quality answer requires an explanation. Please explain what is suggested.